# Переклад імен на українську

Tags: власні-назви, іноземні-імена

Чи правомірно вживати у мовленні та в написанні імена Владімір, Татіана, Васілій, Нікіта, Алєксандр та інші, не перекладаючи їх на українську мову?

Comment: Як на мене, то саме так і треба робити.

Comment: Цікаво, чи є якась нормативно-правова база, стосовно таких ситуацій?